# TRIGGER based on spatial data

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, spatial-index

I have a table called pano_raw that has 3 columns lat, lng, and latlng.

lat and lng are just decimals (10,3) and latlng is a spatial index of type POINT.

This is an example statement that would update the database based on lat and lng.

```
INSERT INTO pano_raw (latlng) VALUES( GeomFromText( 'POINT(-72.34 32.45)' ));
```

I'm trying to create a trigger based off the statement above, that will automatically update the column when I update lat and lng separately.  It's a pain updating the spatial data column everytime with SQL since the query is specialized.  It's much easier to just write a trigger (in theory) that will update when I write a simple decimal value to the table.

The problem I'm having is with the syntax.  Here's my best (2 hour shot at it).

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('POINT(',pano_raw.lng,' ',pano_raw.lat,')');

CREATE TRIGGER trig_pano_raw BEFORE INSERT ON pano_raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET pano_raw.latlng = GeomFromText( @sql ) );
END;
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pano_raw BEFORE UPDATE ON pano_raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET pano_raw.latlng = GeomFromText( @sql ) );
END;
```

I would really appreciate help getting this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pano_raw BEFORE INSERT ON pano_raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.latlng = PointFromWKB( POINT( NEW.lat, NEW.lng ) );
END;
```

Regarding the Update trigger, note that

- 1st, it has to have a different name and
- 2nd, you may want to check which field is updated, like this:

update trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Update_pano_raw BEFORE UPDATE ON pano_raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.lat != OLD.lat) OR (NEW.lng != OLD.lng))
    THEN
        SET NEW.latlng = PointFromWKB( POINT( NEW.lat, NEW.lng ) );
    ELSEIF (NEW.latlng != OLD.latlng)
    THEN
        BEGIN
            SET NEW.lat = X(NEW.latlng);
            SET NEW.lng = Y(NEW.latlng);
        END;
    END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Unknown system variable 'latlng'

Comment: @Phil: Sorry, corrected it. Not sure if `PointFromWKB()` and `POINT()` will do what you want though.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_pano_raw_up BEFORE UPDATE ON pano_raw
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE pano_raw
    SET latlng = PointFromWKB( POINT( NEW.lat, NEW.lng ) );
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Also: There was a comma missing in the string between `NEW.lng` and `NEW.lat`.